# How to Add an Error Message when using a Virtual Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, getter-setter

I have a date field that is not a required field. I am using Chronic to format the user input string to a valid rails format for a date field. If Chronic is unable to parse the date, I would like to raise an error, rendering the edit view with the respective error message and the originally input value. Currently the update is successful if an invalid date is entered but nothing is updated for the service_date field.

new.html.erb

```
<%= f.text_field :service_date_text %>
```

bill.rb

```
require 'chronic'

class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base

  def service_date_text
    service_date.try(:strftime, "%m/%d/%Y")
  end

  def service_date_text=(date)
    if date.present?
      if Chronic.parse(date)
        self.service_date = Chronic.parse(date)
      else
        self.errors.add(:service_date_text, "invalid date format hello.")
      end
    else
      self.service_date = ''
    end
  end
end
```

bills_controller.rb

```
  def update
    @bill = current_account.bills.find(params[:id])
    if @bill.update_attributes(bill_params)
      redirect_to @bill, notice: 'Bill has been successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def bill_params
    params.require(:bill).permit(:description, :notes, :po_number, :service_date_text)
  end
```

Comment: Have you looked at custom validators in ActiveRecord? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`errors` is cleared whenever you run `valid?`, which `update_attributes` does.

Example:

```
irb(main):001:0> album = Album.new
=> #<Album id: nil, name: nil, release_date: nil, rating: nil, genre_id: nil,
artist_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

irb(main):004:0> album.errors.add :artist, "You've selected Justin Bieber (!!!)"
=> ["You've selected Justin Bieber (!!!)"]

irb(main):006:0> album.errors.messages
=> {:artist=>["You've selected Justin Bieber (!!!)"]}

irb(main):007:0> album.valid?
=> true

irb(main):008:0> album.errors.messages
=> {}
```

Don't abuse setters, use proper validations. For example (not tested):

```
  require 'chronic'

  class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base
    validate :service_date_validation

    def service_date_text
      service_date.try(:strftime, "%m/%d/%Y")
    end

    def service_date_text=(date)
      if date.present?
        if Chronic.parse(date)
          self.service_date = Chronic.parse(date)
        else
          self.service_date = false
        end
      else
        self.service_date = ''
      end
    end


    private

      def service_date_validation
        if self.service_date == false
          self.errors.add(:service_date_text, "invalid date format hello.")
        end
      end
  end
```

... There are also some gems which provide date validations, such as:

- https://rubygems.org/gems/validates_timeliness
- https://rubygems.org/gems/date_validator
- https://rubygems.org/gems/rails_validations (disclaimer: I am the author)

... as well as some others...

Comment: Setting the service_date to false was the missing piece for me. I was trying to set the service_date to the input value that Chronic couldn't parse. The thought being that on render edit I would show the error and the originally input value. Also nice explanation of when errors have to be set. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet the issue is that Rails doesn't expect setter methods to add errors. I would make `service_date_text` just an attr_accessor and then call a validate method which sets `service_date` or adds an error.

```
attr_accessor :service_date_text

validate :service_date_text_format

private

def service_date_text_format
  return unless service_date_text # or self.service_date ||= '' and then return
  if date = Chronic.parse(date)
    self.service_date = date
  else
    errors.add(:service_date, 'invalid format')
  end
end
```

Comment: I updated to `self.errors.add(:service_date, "invalid date format.")` but still no errors raised on update.

Comment: I think I understand your problem now. Hopefully the update helps.